# TypeError: update() got multiple values for argument 'upsert'

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo

I'm writing some Python code to update a contest's last backfilled date. I can do this manually in the mongo shell, but when I try to translate the query into pymongo syntax, something goes wrong.

Code:

```
    ShoutletContestConfig.objects().update(
        { '_id': contest },
        { '$set': { 'config.submission.twitter_retweet_last_backfilled': backfill_date } },
        **{ 'upsert': False }
    )
```

(`ShoutletContestConfig` is a mongo Document subclass.)

Error:

```
TypeError: update() got multiple values for argument 'upsert'
```

Attempted mitigation:

- Omit the upsert parameter (Hey, the mongo shell is smart enough to pick a default). When I do this in pymongo, it complains that the query is missing the upsert parameter.
- Literally type `upsert=False` instead of the dict splat, just in case. Nope, same error.
- The pymongo API docs are ambiguous on the proper syntax for `update()`; they just say 'use Django syntax', extremely unhelpful.
- Update pymongo to 2.8 / 2.9. Same error. 3.0 is unfortunately incompatible with our codebase.
- Update mongoengine to 0.9 / 0.10. Same error.

System:

- pymongo 2.7
- mongoengine 0.8.8
- python 3.3.6
- mongo 2.4.9
- Mac OS X 10.10.5

Comment: Have you tried just passing just `False` as the 3rd parameter, instead of `upsert=False`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out double-underscored Django-style syntax is needed.

```
    ShoutletContestConfig.objects().filter(id=contest).update(
        set__config__submission__twitter_retweet_last_backfilled=backfill_date
    )
```